# Why do you need to put #!/bin/bash at the beginning of a script file?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, shebang

I have made [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) scripts before and they all ran fine without `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning.

What's the point of putting it in? Would things be any different?

Also, how do you pronounce `#`? I know that `!` is pronounced as "bang."

How is `#!` pronounced?

Comment: You don't need to and you shouldn't unless you have no choice. Use '#!/bin/sh' while you can and learn about the difference between a (POSIX) shell and bash. There will come a day before your resume grows too much longer when you will find yourself on a system with a different shell and you still want your scripts to work.

Comment: It's pronounced "Hash-Bang" or "She-Bang".

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this is only executed if you run your script as an executable. So if you set the executable flag and then type `./yourscript.extension`, for example, `./helloworld.py` or `./helloworld.sh`, it will look for the interpreter at that top line, which would be `#!/bin/python` or `!#/bin/bash`, whereas when executing the script like `python helloworld.py`, the first line will not be observed because it is commented out. So it is a special sequence for the shell/kernel.

Comment: @JFA is there a change in sequence between bash and python , when using !# for python and #! for bash ?

Comment: @AjeyaAnand no it was a mistype, good catch

Comment: Further reading: https://medium.com/@codingmaths/bin-bash-what-exactly-is-this-95fc8db817bf

Comment: ... because it's many more there than just a bash

Answer (score 547, accepted):

It's a convention so the *nix shell knows what kind of interpreter to run.

For example, older flavors of ATT defaulted to *sh* (the Bourne shell), while older versions of BSD defaulted to *csh* (the C shell).

Even today (where most systems run bash, the *"Bourne Again Shell"*), scripts can be in bash, python, perl, ruby, PHP, etc, etc.  For example, you might see `#!/bin/perl` or `#!/bin/perl5`.

PS:
The exclamation mark (`!`) is affectionately called *"bang"*.  The shell comment symbol (`#`) is sometimes called *"hash"*.

PPS:
Remember - under *nix, associating a suffix with a file type is merely a *convention*, not a *"rule"*.  An *executable* can be a binary program, any one of a million script types and other things as well. Hence the need for `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: I found out about something else useful, $#. What's that called?

Comment: The shebang is not a *shell* convention, it is interpreted by the *kernel* when handling the `execve(2)` syscall; so the shebang is a *kernel* convention, not a shell one.

Comment: Also, it helps some editors like Vim determine the language for syntax highlighting if the file doesn't have an extension. Without the shebang, Vim will display a bash script the same as plain text file.

Comment: ps -u cannot list your script file name unless you add shebang. why is this?

Comment: It makes me wonder whether you need to add `#!/bin/sh` to things like `.profile` and stuff that runs *onload*

Comment: I've seen many answers to the question without a real explanation -- but the last part of your answer "_An executable can be a binary program, any one of a million script types and other things as well. Hence the need for #!/bin/bash._" really nailed it

Comment: So... _hash-bang-slash-bin-slash-bash_?

Comment: `.profile`   or `.bashrc` are sourced not executed so do not want to start with #!

Comment: Note that "officially" (or historically?) the shebang should start with `#! /`. Note the space between the exclamation mark and the slash. The result is that the first four bytes of scripts all start with the same "magic value": the magic value of a shell script. This value is (was) used by for example a utility like `file` to recognize what a file was. Of course, these days, file etc. recognizes every shell just fine even though most people leave out the space.

Comment: @Carlo Wood - you're correct about "#!" being used as a "magic number" - but mistaken that it's a 32-bit value.  Two-byte "magic numbers" aren't uncommon: `"#!" (23 21)`, `"MZ" (4D 5A)`, `"PK" (50 4B)`, etc. etc.

Comment: I didn't make it up myself.

Comment: Doesn't the "#" mean it's a comment (sorry for the stupid question, I am really new to this)

Comment: Some times I see people use `#!/bin/bash -ex` twice in the script. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Boo hiss re: inaccurate verbiage (saying that it's telling the _shell_ vs the _kernel_ what to run).

Comment: @CarloWood, ...not saying you made it up, but pretty sure you got it from an inaccurate source. I learned it as a 16-bit magic number decades ago.

Answer (score 162):

To be more precise the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) `#!`, when it is the first two bytes of an *executable* (`x` [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_%28Unix%29)) file, is interpreted by the [execve(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) system call (which execute programs).

But [POSIX specification for `execve`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/execve.html) don't mention the shebang.

It must be followed by a file path of an interpreter executable (which BTW could even be relative, but most often is absolute).

A nice trick (or perhaps [not so nice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/50557) one) to find an interpreter (e.g. `python`) in the user's `$PATH` is to use the `env` program (always at `/usr/bin/env` on all Linux) like e.g.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
```

Any ELF executable can be an interpreter. You could even use `#!/bin/cat` or `#!/bin/true` if you wanted to! (but that would be often useless)

Comment: See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454) for a discussion of the `#!/usr/bin/env` hack.

Comment: if i want to pass a argument to python how do i do that
actually i want to execute `#!/usr/bin/env bash -x`. How do i do that ?

Comment: its simple i myself found it, just add the param after that `#!/usr/bin/env bash -x`

Comment: `bash` is almost always at `/bin/bash` so your shebang should be `#!/bin/bash -x`

Answer (score 57):

It's called a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29). In unix-speak, # is called sharp (like in music) or hash (like hashtags on twitter), and ! is called bang. (You can actually reference your previous shell command with !!, called bang-bang). So when put together, you get haSH-BANG, or shebang.

The part after the #! tells Unix what program to use to run it. If it isn't specified, it will try with bash (or sh, or zsh, or whatever your $SHELL variable is) but if it's there it will use that program. Plus, # is a comment in most languages, so the line gets ignored in the subsequent execution.

Comment: If I'm already in bash, does it start another bash instance if it sees #!/bin/bash? What if I'm already in bash and I leave it out? Is there any difference?

Comment: @javascriptninja either way it starts a new bash shell. In the case of bash, there really isn't any difference, as long as you're using bash already. The shebang only really matters if (a) you need to run in something that isn't just a shell, like python or perl, or (b) you don't use the bash shell (ie you use zsh) but you need to run something which requires being run in bash.

Comment: However, in my opinion it's good practice to include the shebang, just so someone reading the code knows what's going on.

Comment: Wrong: `execve(2)` syscall don't use the `$SHELL` variable. It is the kernel that is interpreting the shebang.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch that is correct, the elf loader in kernel interprets the shebang. I was stating that $SHELL would be used if no shebang was provided.

Comment: I was really surprised to find that omitting the `#!` works even for something run from `find -exec` (i.e. not directly from a shell).   e.g. with `echo hello` in `/tmp/foo` (executable),  strace and `ltrace -f find [file] -exec /tmp/foo {} +` shows that `execvp(3)` succeeds: It first tries `execve(2)`, which of course fails with `ENOEXEC (Exec format error)`, but then it falls back to `execve`ing `/bin/sh` `/tmp/foo`.  So your claim that "Unix will try $SHELL" is closer to correct than I assumed, thanks to libc's help.  Most programs don't use `execve` directly, but no-#! will break then.

Comment: I upvoted this because it explains nicely why I can run bash scripts without the hashbang. I ran `echo $SHELL` and `/bin/bash` was the result. So something I didn't know before. Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

Every distribution has a default shell. Bash is the default on the majority of the systems. If you happen to work on a system that has a different default shell, then the scripts might not work as intended if they are written specific for Bash.

Bash has evolved over the years taking code from `ksh` and `sh`.

Adding `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of your script, tells the OS to invoke the specified `shell` to execute the commands that follow in the script.

`#!` is often referred to as a "hash-bang", "she-bang" or "sha-bang".

Answer (score 20):

The operating system takes default shell to run your shell script. so mentioning shell path at the beginning of script, you are asking the OS to use that particular shell. It is also useful for [portability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Portability).

Answer (score 20):

The [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) is a directive to the loader to use the program which is specified after the `#!` as the interpreter for the file in question when you try to execute it. So, if you try to run a file called `foo.sh` which has `#!/bin/bash` at the top, the actual command that runs is `/bin/bash foo.sh`. This is a flexible way of using different interpreters for different programs. This is something implemented at the system level and the user level API is the shebang convention.

It's also worth knowing that the shebang is a [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) - a human readable one that identifies the file as a script for the given interpreter.

Your point about it "working" even without the shebang is only because the program in question is a shell script written for the same shell as the one you are using. For example, you could very well write a javascript file and then put a `#! /usr/bin/js` (or something similar) to have a javascript "Shell script".

Answer (score 12):

It is called a **shebang**. It consists of a number sign and an exclamation point character (#!), followed by the full path to the interpreter such as /bin/bash. All scripts under UNIX and Linux execute using the interpreter specified on a first line.

Answer (score 4):

Bash standards for “Bourne-Again shell” is just one type of many available
shells in Linux.

A shell is a command line interpreter that accepts and runs commands.

Bash is often the default shell in most Linux distributions. This is why bash is
synonymous to shell.

The shell scripts often have almost the same syntaxes, but they also differ sometimes. For example, array index starts at 1 in Zsh instead of 0 in bash. A script
written for Zsh shell won’t work the same in bash if it has arrays.

To avoid unpleasant surprises, you should tell the interpreter that your shell script
is written for bash shell. How do you do that?

simply begin your bash script into #!/bin/bash

Answer (score 1):

Also you will see some other parameters after #!/bin/bash, 
for example
`#!/bin/bash -v -x`
read this to get more idea.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124272/what-do-the-arguments-v-and-x-mean-to-bash .

Answer (score 0):

It can be useful to someone that uses a different system that does not have that library readily available.  If that is not declared and you have some functions in your script that are not supported by that system, you should declare #/bin/bash. I've ran into this problem before at work and now I just include it as a practice.