# How do I specify the Bourne shell (not sh)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, sh

I am writing a script and I want it to start with the Bourne shell. As  I understand it, starting the script with:

```
#! /bin/sh
```

will not always specify the Bourne shell, but whatever the OS links to /bin/sh. Is there a way to explicitly specify Bourne?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you meaning something like '#!/bin/bash'? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967902/why-do-you-need-to-put-bin-bash-at-the-beginning-of-a-script-file)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I actually specifically do not want Bash. I need to use the Bourne shell specifically.

Comment: well, that changes system to system, as you said in your question, so you have to change it in your script as well, most of time its pointing to  `bash`

Comment: So there is no way I can force bourne instead of bash if `#!/bin/sh` on my system points to bash?

Comment: @JoshuaStevenson PaoloGibellini is right. This is citation: "... The Bourne shell was developed in 1977 by Stephen Bourne at AT&T's Bell Labs in 1977. It was the default shell of Unix Version 7. Most Unix-like systems contain the file /bin/sh which is either the Bourne shell, or a symbolic link (or hard link) to a compatible shell...Use of the Bourne Shell has largely been suerceded by the Bourne-Again Shell (bash), which supports more user-friendly interactive features such as job control and a command history..."  from http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ush.htm

Comment: The hashbang is always a specific path; you can't specify a shell in general.

Comment: No it's not possible because the information base is over run with people who are lying about which shell to use. They believe they are free software aficionados -- but in fact they are ruining free software and introducing bugs. bash developers and programmers specifically do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original Bourne Shell is not open source, so if you don't already have it, you're SOL.

If you do already have it, just put the location in the shebang.

Simple as that.

Comment: You mean like `#!/bin/bourne`?

Comment: @R4F6 - yeah, if you actually do have the bourne shell **(which you don't, i'll tell you right now)** and it's located at `/bin/bourne` then yes, that would work. but since i'm clairvoyant and already know **you don't have it**, no that won't work.

Answer (score 3):

**<Reminisce_mode_on>**

> Place a colon (:) on the first line.  I used it on older systems
> (A/UX, SCO Unix, Interactive Unix System V Release 3.2 SVR3, circa
> 1989, comes to mind) as the first character in a file to denote a
> Bourne Shell script. It was also recognised by Thompson Toolkit's Korn
> Shell (DOS > v3.2 ). Allowed Unix programmers to shell program in the
> PC environment (DOS/WindowsNT).

**</Reminisce_mode_off>** *Yeah, I'm old. Unix programmers never die, they just become zombie processes.*

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean by "Bourne Shell".

1. Original Bourne Shell, which I believe is not what you are after:

   - proprietary, very limited, and only available on some true UNIX
     systems, such as Solaris, derived from the original AT&T UNIX code.
   - `#!/bin/sh` is the way to get this non-portable shell.
   - Its ability to run true legacy scripts, and its smallness,
     are about the only assets it has in my mind.
     Today's memory gives the size asset less appeal.
2. Modern shells based on Bourne shell syntax. As opposed to, say csh.

   - bash, ksh, zsh are some. Bash is common in Linux environments, and yes, /bin/sh tends to link to one of these.
   - To use a specific shell, use something like `which $SHELL` to
     get an absolute path.
   - `#!/bin/env bash` is less dependent on the shuffling of paths
     found in different operating systems.

     But this portable trick has the risk of choosing
     the wrong shell if `PATH` is not set well enough and
     does not allow arguments, such as `-x`, on the shell.

     It has the advantage
     of `PATH` being able to control which of several shells you use if
     different versions of the same shell are available, which
     ksh is well noted for.

So, if you want more help you will really need to detail the application you are after, and your definition of "Bourne Shell".

Comment: "`#!/bin/sh` is the way to get this non-portable shell." -- in systems that have one as `/bin/sh`. Most modern unix-likes probably don't, but have some newer POSIX sh compatible shell there instead.