# Why does the output from my script say "mv: command not found" but not when I run it on the shell directly?

Tags: bash, shell, mv

I wrote a small script that should rename some files in a directory for me.

```
#!/bin/bash

a=1
for i in *.jpg ; do
        new=$(printf "%04d.jpg" "$a")
        mv "$i" "$new"
        let a=a+1
done

#end of file
```

After running the script is says this: "mv: command not found"

How come there are no error outputs when I run the code directly on the shell like this:

```
for i in *.jpg ; do new=$(printf "%04d.jpg" "$a") ; mv $i $new ; let a=a+1 ; done
```

Comment: Make sure you are not creating / setting a variable called `$PATH` anywhere in the script

Comment: BTW, this is why the POSIX standard suggests that applications use lower-case names for their own environment variables (and thus shell variables, since they share a namespace); it prevents mistakenly overriding variables in the namespace reserved for system use. See fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html

Comment: Also check that you don't have any control characters in that script: `od -c myscript.sh`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It probably is a matter of [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) setting. The `/bin`  directory should be inside your `$PATH`

For debugging purposes, add

```
echo PATH is $PATH
```

at start of your script, and perhaps put `#!/bin/bash -vx`  as your script's first line. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8968514/841108), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html).

As a workaround, replace

```
         mv "$i" "$new"
```

with

```
         /bin/mv "$i" "$new"
```

See [mv(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html)

Comment: I had the same issue and had accidentally trampled all over my PATH variable by using it as a variable in my script. This helped me track down the issue, much obliged!