# Not able to start python program via sh / crontab

Tags: python, linux, shell, cron

I try to start a python program called ocrmypdf from a script or as a cronjob.

It works perfectly from the terminal,

```
pi@piscan:~ $ ocrmypdf 
usage: ocrmypdf [-h] [--verbose [VERBOSE]] [--version] [-L FILE] [-j N] [-n]
            [--flowchart FILE] [-l LANGUAGE] [--title TITLE]
            [--author AUTHOR] [--subject SUBJECT] [--keywords KEYWORDS]
            [-d] [-c] [-i] [--oversample DPI] [-f] [-s]
            [--skip-big MPixels] [--tesseract-config TESSERACT_CONFIG]
            [--pdf-renderer {auto,tesseract,hocr}]
            [--tesseract-timeout TESSERACT_TIMEOUT] [-k] [-g]
            input_file output_file
ocrmypdf: error: the following arguments are required: input_file, output_file
```

but from another shell it breaks for reasons I do not understand.

```
pi@piscan:~ $ sh ocrmypdf
sh: 0: Can't open ocrmypdf
pi@piscan:~ $ which ocrmypdf 
/usr/local/bin/ocrmypdf
pi@piscan:~ $ sh $(which ocrmypdf)
import: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/364.
import: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/364.
from: can't read /var/mail/ocrmypdf.main
/usr/local/bin/ocrmypdf: 10: /usr/local/bin/ocrmypdf: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "then")
```

This is the executed code:

```
pi@piscan:~ $ cat $(which ocrmypdf)
#!/usr/bin/python3

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from ocrmypdf.main import run_pipeline

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(run_pipeline())
```

Comment: Cron jobs do not have access to the X11 server. This is a common FAQ.

Comment: This was actually not the problem. The program doesn't need X11, and I don't know why this error message appears.

Comment: Ah, the `import` command wants X11, but you don't really want to run this shell command at all.

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes sense. Thanks for explaining, I was really confused by this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type `sh ocrmypdf`  you ask the `sh` shell (probably `/bin/sh` which is often a symlink to `/bin/bash` or `/bin/dash`) to interpret the `ocrmypdf` file which is a *Python* script, not a shell one.

So either run `python ocrmypdf` or `python $(which ocrmypdf)` or make the `ocrmypdf` script executable. Then (on Linux at least) [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) will [start the python interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967902/why-do-you-need-to-put-bin-bash-at-the-beginning-of-a-script-file/8968514#8968514), because of the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).

Of course, the `ocrmypdf` script should be in your [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29)

And `crontab` jobs are not running in your desktop environment. So they don't have access to your [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) server [Xorg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server) (or to [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_%28display_server_protocol%29), if you are using it). You could explicitly set the `DISPLAY` variable for that, but I don't recommend doing this.

Comment: I wasn't aware that a call with an interpreter ignores the shebang. python3 /path/to/script.py works fine!