# standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format error"

Tags: python, linux, bash, docker

docker started throwing this error:

> standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format error"

whenever I run a specific docker container with CMD or ENTRYPOINT, with no regard to any changes to the file other then removing CMD or ENTRYPOINT. here is the docker file I have been working with which worked perfectly until about an hour ago:

```
FROM buildpack-deps:jessie

ENV PATH /usr/local/bin:$PATH

ENV LANG C.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        tcl \
        tk \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV GPG_KEY 0D96DF4D4110E5C43FBFB17F2D347EA6AA65421D
ENV PYTHON_VERSION 3.6.0

ENV PYTHON_PIP_VERSION 9.0.1

RUN set -ex \
    && buildDeps=' \
        tcl-dev \
        tk-dev \
    ' \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y $buildDeps --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    \
    && wget -O python.tar.xz "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION%%[a-z]*}/Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tar.xz" \
    && wget -O python.tar.xz.asc "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION%%[a-z]*}/Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tar.xz.asc" \
    && export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" \
    && gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$GPG_KEY" \
    && gpg --batch --verify python.tar.xz.asc python.tar.xz \
    && rm -r "$GNUPGHOME" python.tar.xz.asc \
    && mkdir -p /usr/src/python \
    && tar -xJC /usr/src/python --strip-components=1 -f python.tar.xz \
    && rm python.tar.xz \
    \
    && cd /usr/src/python \
    && ./configure \
        --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions \
        --enable-shared \
    && make -j$(nproc) \
    && make install \
    && ldconfig \
    \
    && if [ ! -e /usr/local/bin/pip3 ]; then : \
        && wget -O /tmp/get-pip.py 'https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py' \
        && python3 /tmp/get-pip.py "pip==$PYTHON_PIP_VERSION" \
        && rm /tmp/get-pip.py \
    ; fi \
    && pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade --force-reinstall "pip==$PYTHON_PIP_VERSION" \
    && [ "$(pip list |tac|tac| awk -F '[ ()]+' '$1 == "pip" { print $2; exit }')" = "$PYTHON_PIP_VERSION" ] \
    \
    && find /usr/local -depth \
        \( \
            \( -type d -a -name test -o -name tests \) \
            -o \
            \( -type f -a -name '*.pyc' -o -name '*.pyo' \) \
        \) -exec rm -rf '{}' + \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove $buildDeps \
    && rm -rf /usr/src/python ~/.cache

RUN cd /usr/local/bin \
    && { [ -e easy_install ] || ln -s easy_install-* easy_install; } \
    && ln -s idle3 idle \
    && ln -s pydoc3 pydoc \
    && ln -s python3 python \
    && ln -s python3-config python-config

RUN pip install uwsgi

RUN mkdir /config

RUN mkdir /logs

ENV HOME /var/www

WORKDIR /config

ADD conf/requirements.txt /config

RUN pip install -r /config/requirements.txt

ADD conf/wsgi.py /config

ADD conf/wsgi.ini /config

ADD conf/__init__.py /config

ADD start.sh /bin/start.sh

RUN chmod +x /bin/start.sh

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["start.sh", "uwsgi", "--ini", "wsgi.ini"]
```

Answer (score 497, accepted):

I forgot to put

```
#!/bin/bash
```

at the top of the sh file, problem solved.

Comment: Thanks! After an hour of hair pulling, and 10 times checking if the architectures (arm/x64 etc) match, your answer saved the day!. p.s.: For windows users like me creating a linux docker, dont forget to remove the windows newline (\r) characters from your file, otherwise the errors keep appearing!

Comment: I got it working after using this solution, earlier I faced same issue.

Comment: I had a space in front of my "#!/bin/bash"

Comment: I had somehow removed the `#` at the beginning of my entrypoint. What a time waste.

Comment: This isn't even Docker-specific, this just always happens when running a Bash script from .NET Core.

Comment: I am fairly new to docker can you please tell me where I need to put this in my DockerFile or in some other location.

Comment: Can someone add an explanation of what this is and why it worked?

Comment: Why need to it on top https://stackoverflow.com/q/8967902/1278112

Comment: in my case i added /bin/sh to my entrypoint.sh file and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 358):

This can happen if you're trying to run an x86 built image on an arm64/aarch64 machine.

You'll need to rebuild the image using the corresponding architecture

Comment: Thank you! I'd recently moved my docker stuff to Kubernetes on a raspberry pi - forgetting the different architecture - had to change all my images to use arm32v7 or arm64v8. You pointed me in the right direction!

Comment: Omg thank you so much, this is so obvious now but hadn't even occurred to me!

Comment: How do you rebuild an image with a different architecture?

Comment: @JasonSwett - Checkout multi-arch builds in docker: https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-build-and-images-the-simple-way/

Comment: As ARM gets more popular on development machines, and people try to  deploy images to x86_64 instances, this will be very useful info! Thank you.

Comment: If anyone has this problem when running the image on an x86 machine, build the docker image with `--platform linux/amd64`.

Comment: Is it possible to run the container under emulation?

Comment: For me I was building image in Mac Apple Silicon(arm) and running on a x86(amd) EC2. Hopefully a lesson and I would pick this mistake much quicker next time :)

Comment: If you are running ```k8s```, you can check your arc ```kubectl describe nodes``` and look out for ```Architecture: <arc>```

Comment: saved my day! I was trying to push to ECS and forgot this step.

Answer (score 239):

This error could also occur if an image was built on a **MacBook Pro** with a **Apple M1 Pro** chip, which is ARM-based, so by default the Docker build command targets `arm64`.

Docker in fact detects the Apple M1 Pro platform as `linux/arm64/v8`

Specifying the platform to both the build command and version tag was enough:

```
# Build for ARM64 (default)
docker build -t <image-name>:<version>-arm64 .

# Build for ARM64 
docker build --platform=linux/arm64 -t <image-name>:<version>-arm64 .

# Build for AMD64
docker build --platform=linux/amd64 -t <image-name>:<version>-amd64 .
```

**Environment**

Chip: Apple M1 Pro, 10 Cores (8 performance and 2 efficiency)
Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57

Comment: ure a life saver man!, I was suffering with that error and performing the references that u shared,  worked like a charm! `ProductName:    macOS, ProductVersion: 12.1, BuildVersion:   21C52`

Comment: This wasn't enough. I needed to add the platform also to my `FROM` imports like  `FROM amd64/python:3.9-slim` and only then I could successfully build a dockerfile for AMD on Apple M1 Pro with the command given above.

Comment: When the deployment still doesn't work, delete all images for other platforms.

Comment: Is `<version>` in `<image-name>:<version>-amd64` is Docker version(20.10.12).. right?

Comment: @JadeHan No, it should be your image version, like so: `docker pull rodbento/webapp:1.0.0-arm64`

Answer (score 88):

Add this code

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

at the top of your script file.

Comment: @akki the entrypoint needs to be executable. If the initial shell file was not, that caused the error.

Comment: @jjmerelo I disagree: in the case when file is not executable – you get a different error, saying "not enough permissions".

Answer (score 87):

If the Docker image is built on an M1 chip and uploaded to be deployed by Fargate then you’ll notice this container error in Fargate:

```sh
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error
```

There’s a couple ways to work around this. You can either:

- Build your docker image using:

```sh
docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64 -t image-name:version .
```

- Update your Dockerfile’s FROM statements with

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 BASE_IMAGE:VERSION
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue, but didn't solved yet.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked with me using only this cmd : docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64 -t image-name:version .

Answer (score 54):

Got the same Error, i was building ARM image after changing to AMD. Issue Fixed

That error usually means you're trying to run this amd64 image on a non-amd64 host (such as 32-bit or ARM).

TRY BUILDING by using **buildx** and specifying  **--platform linux/amd64**

Sample Command

```
docker buildx  build -t ranjithkumarmv/node-12.13.0-awscli . --platform linux/amd64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer save me a lot of time!

Answer (score 28):

If you're getting this in AWS ECS, you probably built the image with an Apple M1 Pro chip. In your Dockerfile, you can add the following:
`FROM --platform=linux/amd64 <image>:<tag>`.

If you're using a sub-image, ex: `FROM <parent_image_you_created>:<tag>` you'll want to make sure the `<parent_image_you_created>:<tag>` was built with `FROM --platform=linux/amd64 <image>:<tag>`.

Comment: Thank you! not sure why there is no hint of this in the error, or on the ECS Console, or the AWS documentation

Answer (score 17):

I'm currently rocking an M1 Mac, I was also running into this issue a little earlier. I actually realized a Fargate task that I had deployed as part of a stack, had not been running for **over a month** because I had deployed it on my M1 Mac laptop. The deploy script was working fine on my old Intel-based Mac.

The error I was just noticing in the CW logs (again the task had been failing for over a month) was just exactly as follows:

```
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error
```

To fix it, in all the `docker build` steps -- since I had one for building a lambda layer, and another for building the Fargate task -- I just updated to add the `--platform=linux/amd64`. Please note, it did not work for me if I for added the tag after the `-t` argument, for example like `img-test:0.1-amd64`. I wonder if perhaps that could be because I was referencing the `:latest` tag later in my script.

In any case, these were the changes necessitated. You'll notice, all I really did was add the `--platform` argument; everything else stayed the same.

```
ecr_repository="some/app"

docker build -t ${ecr_repository} \
        --platform=linux/amd64 \
        --build-arg SOME_ARG='value' \
        .
```

And I'm not sure if it's technically required, but just to be on the safe side, I also updated all the `FROM` statements in my `Dockerfile`s:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ubuntu:<version>
```

Answer (score 13):

Another possible reason for this could be if the file is saved with Windows line endings (CRLF). Save it with Unix line endings (LF) and the file will be found.

Comment: Nice catch! Make sure your file changes make it into the image (ex: rebuild) before you run it again.

Comment: Using Visual Studio Code on Windows there is a setting for default end of line character - turn auto off and set to \n

Answer (score 13):

Extending to the accepted answer:

For an **alpine** (without bash) image:

```
#!/bin/ash
```

at the top of the sh file, solves the problem.

Answer (score 5):

For those trying to build images for aarch64 or armv7l architectures on amd64 Linux system and running into the same error: check if `qemu-user-static` package is installed. If not, install it with `sudo apt install qemu-user-static` on Ubuntu/Debian/Mint etc, or with `sudo dnf install qemu-user-static` on Fedora

Answer (score 4):

None of this worked for me. Why is no one mentioning the [BOM](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark)?

This error occurs if you have a Byte Order Mark at the start of your file.

You can [check with](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109865):

```
head -n 1 yourscript | LC_ALL=C od -tc
```

In Notepad++ you can [save text in UTF-8 without the BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8432691/6077426) by selecting the appropriate option in the Encoding menu:

*Encoding > UTF-8*

Comment: This one worked for me. Changed to normal UTF-8 encoding instead of UTF-8 BOM and it started working.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced same issue in RHEL 7.3, docker 17.05-ce when running offline loaded image. It appeared the default storage driver of RHEL/CentOS changed from [device-mapper](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver) to overlay. Reverting back the driver to devicemapper fixed the problem.

```
dockerd --storage-driver=devicemapper
```

or

```
/etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "storage-driver": "devicemapper"
}
```

Comment: This was the only working solution for me. I prefer the config solution as the other one spawns a new active process and might only fix it temporally.

Answer (score 2):

One more possibility is that #!/bin/bash is not in the very first line. There must be really nothing before it (no empty lines, nothing).

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to the question asked. Although I got the error while calling "docker-compose up" to bring my nodejs application up. Realized that in my "Dockerfile" i had `CMD ["./server.js"]`.

To fix i replaced it with `CMD ["npm","start"]` and that solved the issue. Hope if someone lands here for this exception may find this useful.

Answer (score 2):

`standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error`
For me, it's because there is no `main` package in my go project. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

If you have buildx installed and still run into this error, it might be because cross-platform emulators are missing.

These can be installed like this:

```bash
docker run --privileged --rm tonistiigi/binfmt --install all
```

Source: https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/#building-multi-platform-images

Happened to me when trying to build a `linux/arm64` image via Gitlab pipeline running on a Gitlab runner with platform `linux/amd64`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I "drained" my ECS instanced and "activated" them back again and thereafter the error vanished.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IBR1700 router which runs containers, you may get a similar error when in the router command line after using command `container logs test` (where test is the name of the container).

To fix this you need to build the application so it runs on a different platform. It uses linux/arm/v7.

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged docker/binfmt:a7996909642ee92942dcd6cff44b9b95f08dad64
docker buildx create --name mybuilder
docker buildx use mybuilder
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm/v7 --no-cache -t <username/repository>:<tag> . --push
```

Pushing to the repository with this build means it can run on the router.

https://github.com/cradlepoint/container-samples

Answer (score 0):

For me, my ECS cluster was arm64 architecture, but my docker image was showing  amd64 architecture. I rebuilt my docker image: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/multi-arch/

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem `standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error`, but nothing helped from the answers. Eventually i found that it was old docker version `17.09.0-ce` which is also default on the Circle CI, so just after changing it to the most recent one problem was solved.