# Docker error: standard_init_linux.go:185: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

Tags: postgresql, docker, elixir, docker-compose, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to set my elixir-phoenix app with postgresql database to run with Docker. This is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
# ./Dockerfile

# Starting from the official Elixir 1.5.2 image:
# https://hub.docker.com/_/elixir/
FROM elixir:1.5.2

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Install hex
RUN mix local.hex

# Install rebar
RUN mix local.rebar

# Install the Phoenix framework itself
RUN mix archive.install https://github.com/phoenixframework/archives/raw/master/phx_new.ez

# Install NodeJS 6.x and the NPM
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y -q nodejs

# Set /lib as workdir
WORKDIR /lib
```

And this is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
web:
  build: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile 
  env_file: .env 
  command: mix phx.server # Start the server if no other command is specified
  environment:
    - MIX_ENV=dev
    - PORT=4000
    - PG_HOST=postgres
    - PG_USERNAME=postgres
  volumes:
    - .:/lib 
  ports:
    - "4000:4000"
  links:
    - postgres

test:
  image: phoenixbootstrap_web
  env_file: .env
  command: mix test
  environment:
    - MIX_ENV=test 
    - PORT=4001
    - PG_HOST=postgres
    - PG_USERNAME=postgres
  volumes_from:
    - web
  links:
    - postgres

postgres:
  image: postgres:10.0
  ports:
    - "5432"
```

The image builds successfully, but when I try to install the dependencies with the following command:

```
docker-compose run web mix do deps.get
```

I get these Error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:185: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

PS: I found a couple of answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42494853/standard-init-linux-go178-exec-user-process-caused-exec-format-error), pointing out a missing line at the beginning of a bash file but it doesn't seem to be my case. I run no bash script and my error appears in line 185, not 179.

Comment: http://willi.am/blog/2016/08/11/docker-for-windows-dealing-with-windows-line-endings/

Answer (score 17):

Like you mentioned, one cause could be that the bash file is missing `#!/bin/bash` at the top.

Another possible reason could be if the file is saved with Windows line endings (CRLF). Save it with Unix line endings (LF) and it will be found.

Comment: You saved my day. I was using git config core.autocrlf=true (files were saved with Windows line endings (CRLF)) and didn't even think that it could intervene with docker. Really thank you

Comment: Life saver -http://willi.am/blog/2016/08/11/docker-for-windows-dealing-with-windows-line-endings/

Comment: I was going to say that you saved my day too but actually, I lost it all looking for this answer :(