# How do I create a shortcut for a command line command in Raspbian Stretch?

Tags: linux, command-line, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I am attempting to install RetroPie as an app on Raspbian Stretch and I am done except for creating a desktop shortcut for it. The problem is that the only way to open RetroPie seems to be running a command in the command line. I can’t do it in terminal because it gives me an error saying that it can’t initialize the window. Is there a way to run a command line command as a shortcut or am I going to have to find another way of doing this?

P.S. Here is the tutorial that I followed to install RetroPie:
https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-retropie-app-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Is the screen connected to your RaspberryPi? Is your PC running Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) (on the raspberry) is [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/). So read the manual of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html).

You probably want (once) to edit some [Bash startup file](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) (such as `~/.bashrc`) to define [functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html) and [aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html) there, and you could add *executable* [shell script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script)s somewhere in your [`$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). I recommend having a `$HOME/bin/` directory containing your scripts and executables, and have `$HOME/bin/` early in your `$PATH`.

> I can’t do it in terminal because it gives me an error saying that it can’t initialize the window.

Perhaps you need some [display server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server) (such as [Xorg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server) or [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol))) running (with a [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) or a [window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager)). You could run `Xorg` on your PC (on which you could install Linux) and connect to the raspberry using `ssh -X` then remote applications running on your Raspberry are displayed on your PC. IF your Raspberry is *directly* connected to a screen (via HDMI) you might run some Xorg server on it.

> Is there a way to run a command line command as a shortcut

Yes, by making a shell alias or shell function or shell script. You need to understand how they work and change or create some appropriate file using some [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) (I recommend [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), but the choice is yours and you might use any other editor such as `vim`, `gedit`, etc...): functions and aliases could be defined in your `~/.bashrc`; shell scripts would usually have their own file with a [shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8968514/841108) under your `$HOME/bin/`...

Comment: How do I make it into a shell alias, function, or script?

Comment: I guess you don't understand yet the basics of operating systems and Linux. You should consider spending several weeks reading more about that.

Comment: Ok sorry. Thank you for your time

Comment: However, after spending a few days (at least) reading more about Linux and its shell, you'll find my answer useful. I don't have space and time to explain much more