# tilemaker how to host tiles on ubuntu 23.04

Tags: ubuntu, openstreetmap, mbtiles, tilemaker

Using instructions from [tilemaker](https://github.com/systemed/tilemaker/tree/master) to host tiles locally on Ubunut 23.04

Created croatia.mbtiles successfully but having problems hosting them.

After:

```
sudo apt install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev ruby ruby-dev
sudo gem install sqlite3 cgi glug rack rackup
```

I have noticed that I have not server.rb, so I downloaded entire [server folder](https://github.com/systemed/tilemaker/tree/master/server)

But after running: `ruby server.rb croatia.mbtiles` I get

> server.rb:1:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method` null' for
> main:Object (NameError)

What did I miss?

Comment: It's seems like there's some variable missing or typo in the file.

Did you un-comment the first lline of the server.rb file i.e. `#!/usr/bin/ruby`?

Comment: You don't need to do that, that's how your shell interpreter knows how to run the file... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967902/why-do-you-need-to-put-bin-bash-at-the-beginning-of-a-script-file

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that the folder was missing.

Did you `git clone https://github.com/systemed/tilemaker.git`?

If not, please do that and follow the steps described in the "[Out-of-the-box setup](https://github.com/systemed/tilemaker/tree/master#out-of-the-box-setup)" section of the [Readme](https://github.com/systemed/tilemaker/blob/master/README.md) file. There are multiple steps before you run the server, incl. setting up the directory structure as described.

If that's already done, please list *all* steps you followed in your description.

Thanks!