# Make Python script globally executable

Tags: python-2.7

Let's say I've got this one-line Python module called `say_hello.py`.

```
print 'Hello World'
```

How can I make the script executable from any location in my terminal? That is, having `Hello World` printed outside the Python interpreter anywhere on my system. I'm running on OS X Mavericks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366775/what-does-the-line-bin-sh-mean-in-a-unix-shell-script

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### General *nix answer

First line of script should look something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

although the exact path may be different on your system.  Then, make the script executable and put it somewhere in your PATH.

Comment: @trevorDashDash: save the file with no `.py` on it.  You only need the `.py` if you want to be able to import the file.  If you want both to import the script under certain situations and run it without the `.py` in others, you could create a link to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Add as the first line of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

or, for a python3 script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

The shell (actually the kernel) will use the first Python/Python3 interpreter found in your $PATH.

Comment: just for reference: `#!/usr/bin/python` vs. `#!/usr/bin/env python` https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608