# Calling a Python Function from local working directory

Tags: python

I have a python script called `script.py` that takes in arguments and gives the output. Every time I use the script, I copy it to local working directory and then execute it as `python script.py --arg1=a`. I was wondering if there is a way to call the python function in local working directory without copying it, like how u can copy u c++ build files to /usr/local/bin and call it from anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: You can manipulate sys.path in python script to expose libs for import into Python environment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Python script globally executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295131/make-python-script-globally-executable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this steps:

1. put `#!/usr/bin/python` on the first line of your script.
2. making it executable by using `chmod +x script.py`
3. Move it to `/usr/bin` directory

then try to execute script.py in the terminal.

Comment: `/usr/bin` probably not the best spot. Better to edit the `PATH` to add a `$HOME/bin`, for example

Answer (score 0):

Add a shebang to the script - [Should I put #! (shebang) in Python scripts, and what form should it take?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts-and-what-form-should-it-take)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print('hello')
```

Make it executable

```
chmod +x script.py
```

Then you can execute it from the local (or any other) directory

```
./script.py
```

If you want to be globally available, you need to edit your `PATH`