# Crontab @reboot for AIX

Tags: cron, aix, reboot

I want a script on my `AIX machine` to be executed upon server reboot. I tried below command in my crontab file but received an error.

> **@reboot sleep 300 && /usr/bin/sh /opt/script.sh**
>
> A line of the crontab file:
> **@reboot sleep 300 && /usr/bin/sh /opt/script.sh**
>
> contains the following error:
> **0481-079 Reached a symbol that is not expected.**

Comment: Crontab is meant for periodic events. For system-startup, there is a SystemV-style init-system. See /etc/init.d

Answer (score 1):

To execute a script when an AIX server reboots, you have two options, both of which involve the [/etc/inittab file](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/filesreference/inittab.html).

Option #1 is to insert the call to your script as an inittab entry, with [mkitab](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/m_commands/mkitab.html); for example:

```
mkitab 'myscript:2:once:/opt/script.sh'
```

This assumes you've made /opt/script.sh executable (`chmod +x /opt/script.sh`) and [put a proper sh-bang line in it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7366775/4957508). There's no need to prefix it with /usr/bin/sh once you've done that.

---

Option #2 is to leverage the existing runlevel 2 script directory, which is invoked from /etc/inittab with the `l2:2:wait:/etc/rc.d/rc 2` entry. Simply place your (properly executable) /opt/script.sh file in /etc/rc.d/rc2.d named with a leading `S`, to indicate it should be started in runlevel 2. For example:

```
cp /opt/script.sh /etc/rc.d/rc2.d/S90-script.sh
```

Here I've prefixed it with "S90", which has the leading `S` to indicate startup and 90 as a rough way to sequence items within runlevel 2.  **The caveat** to this solution is that the init system will assume that your script supports a parameter -- `start` or `stop`. During boot, it will call your script with the "start" parameter. If your existing script silently ignores any parameters, you're fine. Otherwise, you may need to modify it or write a wrapper script.